# google maps Print data from xml to info tab

Tags: google-maps

I have google maps .. markers gets data from xml.. everything works ok.. but i want to write information from xml to tabs.. but i dont know how do it.. pls look my codes.. help me :((

```
          var gmarkers = [];
          var gicons = [];
           map = null;

var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/intake.png',

      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),

      new google.maps.Point(0,0),

      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));

  var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
      new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));

  var iconShape = {
      coord: [9,0,6,1,4,2,2,4,0,8,0,12,1,14,2,16,5,19,7,23,8,26,9,30,9,34,11,34,11,30,12,26,13,24,14,21,16,18,18,16,20,12,20,8,18,4,16,2,15,1,13,0],
      type: 'poly'
  };

   var contentString = [

      '<div id="tabs">',

      '<ul>',

        '<li><a href="#tab-1"><span>Info</span></a></li>',
        '<li><a href="#tab-2"><span>Info</span></a></li>',
        '<li><a href="#tab-3"><span>Photo</span></a></li>',
      '</ul>',

      '<div id="tab-1">',

      ' i must add info here',

      '</div>',
      '<div id="tab-2">',

       '<p>and here</p>',

      '</div>',

      '<div id="tab-3">',

        '<p>Any info and photo will be here.. <br/> <img src="images/logo.gif" height="60" ></p>',
      '</div>',
      '</div>'
    ].join('');  

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 

content: contentString

  });


      // A function to create the marker and set up the event window

function createMarker(latlng,name,html,category) {

    var contentString = html;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: latlng,
        icon: gicons[category],
        shadow: iconShadow,
        map: map,
        title: name,

        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5

        });

        // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
        marker.mycategory = category;      

        marker.myname = name;

        gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
}

      // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==

      function show(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
          }
        }
        // == check the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
      }

      // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
      function hide(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
          }
        }
        // == clear the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
        // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
        infowindow.close();
      }

      // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
      function boxclick(box,category) {
        if (box.checked) {
          show(category);
        } else {
          hide(category);
        }

      }







  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, 48.0000),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


   google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });
```

Here is xml

```
      // Read the data

      downloadUrl("xml/cat.xml", function(doc) {

  var xml = xmlParse(doc);

  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
         var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var html = contentString;
          var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
          // create the marker
          var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category);
        }


        // == show or hide the categories initially ==
        show("intake");
        hide("reservoir");
        hide("wps");
        show("wtp");
        hide("wwps");
        hide("wwtp");
        // == create the initial sidebar ==

      });


 toggleKML = function(x) { 
          i = x;
        //alert(i);
        //alert(toggleArray[0]);
        //alert(toggleArray[1]);
        //alert(toggleArray[2]);        
        if (toggleArray[i] == 1) {
        kmlArray[i].setMap(null);

        toggleArray.splice(i,1,'0');                  
        }
        else {
        kmlArray[i].setMap(map);

        toggleArray.splice(i,1,'1');        
        }
 }}
</script>
```

Guys Please help me ((..

more than 12 hours i work over this but it not work ((..

How can i put xml data into contentstring ?

my xml example also..

```
<marker code="20070" id="WWS7" name="8 Wells Nisaqala Gallery" title="NWSSP-2" capacity="9.84" completed="0" lat="xxx" lng="xx"  category="intake"/>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'tabs' - do you mean an infowindow which displays different content when you click different markers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content of the infowindow, based on the click event on the marker.  You also need to do this using a closure most likely.  Right now you're setting the same content every time, as `contentString` never changes.  You just need to set that content in your click event handler, using values from your XML file.

Comment: Thanks for answer.. But i dont know how do it.. (( i`ve checked more than one option but not worked.. 

have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I've realized what you're asking for, you could check my code here: http://turom-mice.it/condorincentive/incentive.html (use Firebug to get scripts and the associated XML file)
Code is commented as much as possible, but if you need explanations, just ask.
Code is the result of various searches and readings here and Google Maps v3 API/examples.

Hope it helps.
rash*